# Как обратится к элементу у которого меняется класс?

Tags: javascript

На странице есть `<div class=popup_765>`, а после обновления страницы этот класс может иметь уже другое имя `<div class=popup_768>`.  Меняются только цифры после символа подчеркивания. Как можно обратится к такому элементу?

Comment: Обновление страницы - это перезагрузка или происходят какие то изменения скриптами?

Comment: выбрать все элементы в которых в атрибуте class встречается popup и найти нужный

Comment: в зависимости от родителя  document.querySelector(.parent div) или по dom-элементам document.body.firstChild (очень-очень длинно придется писать)

Comment: SwaD перезагрузка страницы

Comment: Kjuri ну а если ещё элемент появится на странице? Путь разве не изменится?

Comment: Возможно, вы пытаетесь решить совершенно другую проблему? Если элементов может быть несколько и у них нет каких то четких родителей, которые не меняются, то скорее всего, эти див никак не определить.

Comment: @User зависит от вашей страницы и возможности прицепить модалке или ее родителям хоть какой-то стабильный класс. В идеале - либо сам элемент, либо родителя уникализировать и уже по селектору выбирать, а dom-это уже самый крайний случай и неизбежность с полным пониманием потенциальных проблем.

Answer (score 0):

Если он у вас один такой, то проще простого:

```
// выбрать элемент по классу начинающемуся с 'popup'
document.querySelector('[class^=popup]')

// или если хочется уточнить, что это обязательно 'div'

// выбрать 'div' с классом начинающемся с 'popup'
document.querySelector('div[class^=popup]')
```

```js
let popup = document.querySelector('[class^=popup]');
console.log('popup:', popup)
```

```html
<div class="popup_12345">текст</div>
```

Рекомендую в обязательном порядке для ознакомления [Знаете ли вы селекторы?](https://learn.javascript.ru/css-selectors)